# "none of the providers can be installed" when I ran "sudo yum -y install nvidia-driver-latest-dkms"

Tags: linux, centos, cuda

I want to install NVIDIA Driver. I ran `sudo yum -y install nvidia-driver-latest-dkms`, but I got the following problem:

> Error:   Problem: package
> nvidia-driver-latest-dkms-3:545.23.08-1.el7.x86_64 requires
> yum-plugin-nvidia, but none of the providers can be installed
>
> - cannot install the best candidate for the job
> - nothing provides python needed by yum-plugin-nvidia-0.3-1.el7.noarch
> - nothing provides python needed by yum-plugin-nvidia-0.5-1.el7.noarch

I have tried installing python by running `sudo yum -y install python38`, but the problem before still exists.

Comment: Please edit your question to add which repos you expect to get nvidia driver (and python38)  from, and the output of `yum repolist`    For example, the instructions at  https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html#centos7   have you add a repo, because there's a few packages involved, plus dependencies.